# How to set Angular Kendo grid button text on center?

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui

Currently I am using grid view of Kendo UI for angular. Here I have some button on grid but the problem is the text of the button is not in center, however I have applied some styles like (`text-align:center`) but nothing works.
Here is my button template

```
<kendo-grid-command-column title="SPO Item Count" width="120">
                                            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                                                <button pButton type="button"
                                                        style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:10px; width: 100px; text-align:center" (click)="onEditCostClick(dataItem);"
                                                        class="p-mr-2 p-mb-2 p-ripple p-button p-component">
                                                    {{dataItem.spoItemCount}}
                                                </button>
                                            </ng-template>
                                        </kendo-grid-command-column>
```

and here is what I get in browser

[image]

Comment: do you have a sandbox or stackblitz example on line ? the text should be in the middle/center  unless you have a display reset elsewhere. (`display:flex` ? ) if it is a flex reset, `align-items:center` will do or `align-item-center` BS4 class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<kendo-grid-command-column title="SPO Item Count" width="120">
                                            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                                                <button pButton type="button"
                                                        style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:10px; width: 100px; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;" (click)="onEditCostClick(dataItem);"
                                                        class="p-mr-2 p-mb-2 p-ripple p-button p-component">
                                                    {{dataItem.spoItemCount}}
                                                </button>
                                            </ng-template>
                                        </kendo-grid-command-column>
```